# WARNING: npm peer requirements not installed: react@15.0.2 installed, react@0.14.x needed

Tags: meteor, reactjs, npm

I kept on getting the following warning as I try to develop app in Meteor with react:
    "W20160519-01:55:40.709(1)? (STDERR) WARNING: npm peer requirements not installed:
    W20160519-01:55:40.712(1)? (STDERR)  - react@15.0.2 installed, react@0.14.x needed
    W20160519-01:55:40.713(1)? (STDERR)  - react-dom@15.0.2 installed, react-dom@0.14.x needed
    W20160519-01:55:40.713(1)? (STDERR)  - react-addons-pure-render-mixin@15.0.2 installed, react-addons-pure-render-mixin@0.14.x needed
    W20160519-01:55:40.714(1)? (STDERR) 
    W20160519-01:55:40.716(1)? (STDERR) Read more about installing npm peer dependencies:
    W20160519-01:55:40.719(1)? (STDERR)   http://guide.meteor.com/using-   packages.html#peer-npm-dependencies
    W20160519-01:55:40.719(1)? (STDERR)" without knowing the cause of it.

I updated meteor to 1.3.2.4 and updated npm to 2.x; delete and reinstall npm via meteor npm install, all to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was as a result of kadira:react-layout installation. The fact is that kadira:react-layout depends on react@0.14.x while npm installs react@15.x.

Thus any body experiencing this warning should just remove kadira:react-layout from the .meteor/packages to get rid of the warning.

To still use react-layout, copy [this file](http://github.com/kadirahq/meteor-react-layout/blob/master/lib/react_layout.js)into /lib/react-layout.js and continue to use it pending when it will be made compatible with react@15.x.

I hope this helps someone out there.